# Limit a parent div to be the height of its shortest child with overflow using tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a dashboard with a main area, and a side bar with an activity feed. Sometimes there is more "activity" than there is main content. Is there a pure-css way to make sure the height of the activity feed is limited to the height of the main area? One thing that makes this complicated is that the main area doesn't have a fixed height.

Here's a mock of the problem:

[image: dashboard with main and aside]

This felt... just so close... but it doesn't get there. Starting to suspect it's impossible without JS?

https://play.tailwindcss.com/O3pKf1ub82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the sidebar into a `absolute` element and parent a `relative` element.

This makes it rely on its parent. As the main content grows, so does the parent and the sidebar matches parent height.

Don’t forget to set a min height, e.g. `min-h-[10rem]` for the main content to avoid the sidebar being too small.

Demo link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/lyeySM51kQ

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! I had all but concluded this was impossible.